A possibly Polish movie about drug dealers
All I can recall is that there was a young guy who had a bald tattooed big friend and both were selling drugs (cocaine) i think. After a while they get in touch with a very crazy guy that also rapes the young guy later, and they start an organisation of selling coke (still not sure if it's about coke but whatever).
The movie's title was translated in my language and it meant 'The drug dealers' but I can't find this movie anywhere. And I think it was Polish. I saw the movie on HBO a couple months ago. The scene where the young guy gets raped by the gangs leader (the very crazy guy) happens at a party in a guy's home. In the morning the host's parents come back early and he gets so mad that he nearly kills his mother by beating her.
When they were selling they hide the drugs somewere outside so the cops can't find anything on them. That's almost all I can recall from the movie except that the big tattooed bald guy, the friend of the young guy, I've seen him in other movies for sure, he was the only actor I could recognize but unfortunetly I can't tell what movies I've seen him before. Big bald with tattoos and a very not friendly face. Please help :D The year should be somewhere near 2000 or later.

Any idea what year or even decade it was from?

More information you provide , better chances of getting answer. Any info or physical disscription of actorsched ,release year or when and where you watched etc

I've found it.Svartur á leik(Black's Game) from 2012.thanks for trying.

That's great. You can always answer your own question (preferably explaining in which way it fits to the descriptions from the question) and approve it.

Found it. Black's Game from 2012. I described in the question all I know about the movie. It's a great movie and I haven't found the time to see it in full so I can't bring more details yet about it but I recommend it to anyone who is interested.

Please try to explain in which way this movie fits to the descriptions from the question.

why should i explain? it's my own answer to my own question

For people to see that it is a proper answer. It really doesn't matter if you know it is correct. We're supposed to give properly explained answers to questions here, since the questions and answers are not only for you but for everyone.

Anyway it fits perfectly since it's the movie i was looking for and all i asked in the question was the only things i've seen in the movie because i haven't seen it to the end which is the reason i wanted to find it.

Aw ok.Glad to help then.

Better? I don't really know much about this site since i'm new but i'm looking forward to learn more about it and help who i can.Great site.

I think you may be after The Danish film Pusher (1996)

The film begins in Copenhagen with a low-level drug dealer Frank (Kim Bodnia) going to a heroin deal with his sidekick Tonny (Mads Mikkelsen). The pair only manage to sell some of their product, and then waste time about town. Frank then visits his friend Vic (Laura Drasbæk), a prostitute who holds some of Frank's stash for a fee. Vic wants to have a serious relationship with Frank, but Frank prefers to keep it purely casual.
Frank is visited by a former cell mate, a Swede named Hasse (Peter Andersson), and the pair set up a large drug deal. Frank visits his supplier, the Serbian local drug lord Milo (Zlatko Burić), to get the heroin. Already owing Milo some money, Frank cannot cover the cost of the heroin, but Milo allows him to take the drugs provided that he immediately returns with the money.
The deal goes bad, however, when police arrive. In the process of evading the police, Frank dumps the heroin in a lake. At the station, police officers convince Frank that Tonny has delivered a confession that implicates Frank, but he still does not admit to anything. When Frank is released after 24 hours he returns to Milo to explain how he lost the money and the drugs. Milo does not believe Frank's story and demands that he pay back even more than he already owes. Frank then immediately seeks Tonny out and savagely beats him with a baseball bat.
Milo's cynical henchman Radovan (Slavko Labović) accompanies Frank to help him collect on some of his own debts to use toward his debt with Milo. The pair have a friendly conversation and Radovan shares his secret desire to open a restaurant. Radovan tries to force an addict customer of Frank's to rob a bank to cover his debt, but the addict commits suicide in front of them. As Frank makes other disastrous attempts to earn money, Vic becomes increasingly insistent that they behave as a couple. He takes her to several clubs and makes plans to drive her to the veterinarian to see her sick dog.
Frank finally makes a deal, but his drug mule betrays him and switches the heroin for baking soda. Radovan drops his friendly demeanour and begins threatening Frank with serious injury should he fail to pay up soon. Frank goes on a desperate rampage, stealing some money and drugs from the gym of some drug-dealing body builders, but he is soon picked up by Radovan and tortured. Frank manages to escape and makes plans to flee with Vic to Spain. After successfully making his final deal in Copenhagen, Frank receives a call from Milo, who promises to accept a token payment to put an end to their feud. When Frank bluntly informs Vic that their plans to flee are cancelled, she steals his stash of money and runs off.
The film ends with Frank grimly catching his breath as his enemies throughout the city prepare to dispose of him.

Trailer
imdb link
Wiki link

Unfortunatly this ain't it.thanks for trying.
